# i am a new of swift coder ,and i cant include a class

Tags: swift, delegates

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var text: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        name.delegate = self


        // Do any additional setup after loading
    }
```

these are some of my code
when name.delegate = self occured an error :

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'name'
```

i typed these code from book ,how to fixed it ?is the problem of swift grammar???

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
text.delegate = self
```

because you add `UITextFieldDelegate` which need to conform a delegate of any `UITextField` you add in your code.

With that when you did something with your `UITextField` it will call its required delegate methods.

For more info refer this Apple Documentation on [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/).

Comment: why? could u explain a little of it?

Comment: OK OK ! i knew it  !thank u very much! it is a name of my textfield